# Prove that the number of integers between in $[1,n]$ that are relatively prime to $n$ is $n\prod_{i = 1}^{t} (1- \frac{1}{p{i}})$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Prove using the principle of inclusion and exclusion:

Let $n$ be a number that can be written as a product of prime numbers, $n=p_1^{i_1}p_2^{i_2}\cdots p_t^{i_t}$

Prove that the number of integers between in $[1,n]$ that are strangers (relatively prime) to $n$ is $n\prod_{i = 1}^{t}\left(1- \frac{1}{p_i}\right)$

I see that the group of element I am working with is all the integer number between $1$ and $n$. And I also know that to find the number of numbers between $1$ and $n$ that are divisible by $p$ a prime numbers I show divide $\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{p}}\right \rfloor $.

I got $\sum_{k=0}^{t} (-1)^k\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{p_k}}\right \rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^{t} (-1)^k\left \lfloor{\frac{p_1^{i_1}p_2^{i_2}...p_t^{i_t}}{p_k}}\right \rfloor. $

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "strangers to n" mean? Do you want $ \gcd(n, m ) = 1 $?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This seems to be a pretty straightforward application of PIE, so please list out your work and be explicit about what you need help with.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question. It is possible that my approach is wrong. I could use a hint! And yes that's what I mean with strangers.

Comment: Strangers appear to mean relatively prime, like 5 and 12.  Must be something weird in language translation.  Also the "pi" in the product should read $p_i$.